# How to create a tree with filtered nodes from drupal taxonomy

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to create a menu tree in drupal like this:

```
- term 1
    node 1
    node 2
  - sub-term 1
        node 3
        node 4
  + sub-term 2
  - sub-term 3
        node 5
      - sub-sub-term 1
             node 6
+ term 2
etc.
```

(Sub-term 2 and term 2 are toggled closed.)

Some requirements:

- Output this using something like JQuery Menu to get an interactive tree
- Filter the nodes by cck type
- Filter the nodes by cck field
- Only have terms with nodes or other active terms in them show up
- Mark the current node as such, and automatically open the tree to that point

Do I have to write this myself, or are there a combination of modules that can do it? I've got Advanced Taxonomy Blocks, which is pretty close, but it doesn't list the nodes.

Comment: Very strange taxonomy tree, subterm is child of node that attached in it. Usually parent term has subtree of children terms.
I think only manually coded menu is possible here, no ready module exists for it.

Comment: Maybe my example is misleading, but I didn't mean to imply that the sub-terms are children of the nodes, merely that the tree shows both a given terms nodes, and their sub-terms. I'll adjust the sketch slightly...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and the [DHTML Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) module linked in the previous answer would get you pretty close. You'll need a view for your content to do the filtering. Here is an excerpt about Taxonomy menu from its project page:

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!
>
> Features
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
> - Integrate with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto): use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

Answer (score 1):

Just make your own custom menu and use the [DHTML Menu module](https://www.drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) to make it expand/contract on click. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... uses Javascript to reduce the number of page loads when using nested menus; this is particularly useful with Drupal's administration system.
>
> Ordinarily in Drupal, in order to see the sub-items in a menu, you need to click the link of this item and wait for a full page load. After enabling DHTML Menu, clicking a menu link once will expand it to reveal its sub-items without reloading the page. A double-click on the item will load the page normally. Additionally, a cookie stores which menus are open and which are closed, so that the state of the menus remain consistent as you navigate around the site.

Answer (score 1):

I think this module will do what you want -- [Taxonomy field menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_field_menu).

It will build a traditional menu based on the connection between terms and nodes.